# Layout positioning with Constraint-Layout helper Flow in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm using the Constraint-Layout helper Flow to build a user-interface similar to a calculator.

I'm having a problem with positioning the referenced views which are referenced by my Flow object.

Please see the attached picture [my flow layout pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmqT7.png)

As you can see, I want to move the single bottom button to the top of layout. How should I move it to the left or to the right of the layout using the Flow helper.

Here's the code of the Flow helper object that creates the layout I need to modify.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
    android:id="@+id/flow"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"

    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent = "0.8"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids ="a,b,c,d,e"
    android:background="@drawable/my_own_drawable"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:flow_verticalGap = "10dp"
    app:flow_horizontalGap = "10dp"
    app:flow_maxElementsWrap = "2"
    app:flow_wrapMode = "aligned"
    app:flow_verticalAlign="top" // I Thought this line would do the job, but it did not
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mytextview"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    >
</androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following buttons will be created:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/e"
    android:layout_width = "0dp"
    android:layout_height = "0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent = "0.1"
    android:text="17"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/no1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height = "0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent = "0.1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:enabled="false"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    />
```

Notice that they both have the same horizontal weight = 1 . Also, button with id = no1 
is still visible but has a transparent background and is enabled to false.
So, it wont be clicked by user.

We can move the visible button(id = e) to left or right of layout with the following line
inside the Flow helper object:

```
app:constraint_referenced_ids ="e,no1,a,b,c,d"  //will move button( id = e) to left side

app:constraint_referenced_ids ="no1,e,a,b,c,d"  //will move button( id = e) to right
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to change the ordering in the [Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow) widget by setting the reference IDs in the order you prefer

```
 constraintFlow.referencedIds = intArrayOf(R.id.my_view_id_1,R.id.my_view_id_2)
 constraintFlow.requestLayout()
```